# How to get $error values including ngIf child scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm in a new project which is using angular.js. I've no experience with angular at all but I have to solve a litte probleme.

There is an input-field looking like this:

```
<input
  name="{{ getTheId() }}"
  type="number"
  ng-model="myModel"
  ng-min="1"
  ng-max="500"
/>
```

When entering an Number greater than the max, the input in the DOM getting extra style-classes like `class="... ng-invalid-max ... "` and also an output like this

```
<p>{{modelController.$error}}</p>
```

would print something like that:

```
{"max":true}
```

The problem: When adding some ngIf around like this

```
<div ng-if="someCondition">
  <input ... >
</div>
```

the modelController.$error is always empty now.  I've found out, that an ngIf adds a new Scope. But I need the information at the same place like before because some labels with error-warnings getting triggerd by this in the DOM.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: `ng-if` removes the DOM elements, if you want to keep getting access to the DOM elements (and the `modelController.$error`), you need to keep the elements (hidden) by using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: How are you creating the `modelController` object? Please provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: Using functions inside AngularJS interpolations should be avoided as as they are invoked one or more times every digest cycle, .e.g. avoid `{{ getTheId() }}`.